# XenServer Fails to Backup:

Tags: backup, xenserver

I've had this issue on and off for a year and I figured I should finally post something.

When going Server -> Backup on a three host pool of XenServer 6.5 SP1, I get "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Googling this didn't get me too far, except an older post here without a direct solution:

http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/299979-backup-through-xencenter-fails-with-message-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond-after-a-period-of-time-or-established-connection-failed-beca/

I'm not losing connection to the pool when this error happens. The error happens on multiple workstations, and on two different pools. In the most recent case, I have been able to get a backup of the pool master, but the member servers fail with this error.

XenCenter Logs:

```
2016-03-24 11:39:54,326 DEBUG XenAdmin.Controls.ConsolePanel [Main program thread] - ConsolePanel: CloseVNCTimer(Control domain on host XenBlade5): Timer stopped and removed in delegate
             2016-03-24 11:40:06,268 DEBUG XenAPI.HTTPHelper [16] - Caught exception doing HTTP GET from 192.168.2.26 to C:\Installs\XenServer\P1-XB2.xbk
             2016-03-24 11:40:06,269 DEBUG XenAPI.HTTPHelper [16] - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at XenAPI.HTTP.CopyStream(Stream inStream, Stream outStream, DataCopiedDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate)
   at XenAPI.HTTP.Get(DataCopiedDelegate dataCopiedDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Uri uri, IWebProxy proxy, String path, Int32 timeout_ms)
   at XenAPI.HTTP_actions.get_host_backup(DataCopiedDelegate dataCopiedDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Int32 timeout_ms, String hostname, IWebProxy proxy, String path, String task_id, String session_id)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(UpdateProgressDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, IXenConnection connection, XenRef`1 task, Session& session, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at XenAPI.HTTP.CopyStream(Stream inStream, Stream outStream, DataCopiedDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate)
   at XenAPI.HTTP.Get(DataCopiedDelegate dataCopiedDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Uri uri, IWebProxy proxy, String path, Int32 timeout_ms)
   at XenAPI.HTTP_actions.get_host_backup(DataCopiedDelegate dataCopiedDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Int32 timeout_ms, String hostname, IWebProxy proxy, String path, String task_id, String session_id)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(UpdateProgressDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, IXenConnection connection, XenRef`1 task, Session& session, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
         2016-03-24 11:40:06,430 INFO  XenAPI.Session [16] - Invoking XML-RPC method task.destroy
         2016-03-24 11:40:06,474 ERROR XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction [16] - System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(UpdateProgressDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, IXenConnection connection, XenRef`1 task, Session& session, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(AsyncAction action, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.HostBackupRestoreAction.Run()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction.RunWorkerThread(Object o)
         2016-03-24 11:40:06,475 ERROR XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction [16] -    at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(UpdateProgressDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, IXenConnection connection, XenRef`1 task, Session& session, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(AsyncAction action, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.HostBackupRestoreAction.Run()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction.RunWorkerThread(Object o)
         2016-03-24 11:40:06,476 WARN  Audit [16] - Operation failure: HostBackupRestoreAction: NCUPOOL: Pool 30a9e997-12d4-46b1-4ab3-92bc5bfe9bb7 (NCUPOOL): Host 49c45d83-e23a-4bb0-9002-7a0216637cf7 (XenBlade2): Backing up server 'XenBlade2', 87 MB received... 
         2016-03-24 11:40:06,477 DEBUG XenAdmin.Actions.ActionBase [16] - System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(UpdateProgressDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, IXenConnection connection, XenRef`1 task, Session& session, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(AsyncAction action, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.HostBackupRestoreAction.Run()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction.RunWorkerThread(Object o)
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(UpdateProgressDelegate progressDelegate, FuncBool cancellingDelegate, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, IXenConnection connection, XenRef`1 task, Session& session, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAPI.HTTPHelper.Get(AsyncAction action, Boolean timeout, DataCopiedDelegate dataRxDelegate, String path, String hostname, Delegate f, Object[] p)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.HostBackupRestoreAction.Run()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction.RunWorkerThread(Object o)`
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Any tips?

Thanks!